# I cannot install react How can I fix this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I am new to react. I am trying to install react with create-react-app. I have installed node.js and npm. It has been 40 minutes, nothing is happening. I have tried to do install it again but showing me the same thing.

[image]

Comment: That's not "installing react", that's "running create-react-app".

Comment: How can I fix this then?

Comment: remember to add the `--verbose` flag if you want to see what it's actually doing, so `npx create-react-app demo --verbose`.

Comment: Make sure NPM is up to date. And are you able to install other packages using NPM?

Comment: @jarmod the npm version information is right there. Node 12.16.1, npm 6.13.4

Comment: yes it is the updated version

Comment: Try these steps, with yarn, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the global create-react-app. As long as it's on your system it will interfere with npx.